# Show $S$ is countable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, set-theory

The problem on the textbook says,

> Given a set $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the property that for every $\mathbf{x}$ in $S$ there is an $n$-ball $B(\mathbf{x})$ such that $B(\mathbf{x}) \cap S$ is countable. Prove that $S$ is countable.

**My attempt**

I claim that $B(\mathbf{x}; r) \cap S$ is countable for every $r > 0$ and $x \in S$. My argument goes like:

If $B(\mathbf{x}; r) \cap S$ is countable for some $r > 0$, then $B(\mathbf{x}; r^\prime) \cap S$ is also countable for all positive $r^\prime <  r$.
Now assume $ r$ is the largest radius for which $B(\mathbf{x}; r) \cap S$ is countable. Consider the all the points $\mathbf{y} \in S$ and $\lVert \mathbf{x} -\mathbf{y} \rVert = r$. For all $n$-balls $B(\mathbf{y}; r_y)$, $B(\mathbf{y}; r_y) \cap S$ is countable, where $r_y$ is the largest radius for which $B(\mathbf{y}; r_y) \cap S$ is countable. Take the smallest of all $r_y = r_o$. Then $B(\mathbf{x}; r + r_o ) \cap S$ is countable, a contradiction. Hence, $B(\mathbf{x}; r) \cap S$ is countable for all $r > 0$. This means we can pick sufficiently large $r$ such that $B(\mathbf{x}; r) \cap S = S$ and show that $S$ is countable.

I feel a little uneasy about this proof because it is not the way the textbook wants me to solve the problem. I just want to know if this proof is valid or not. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if $S=\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @zkutch Rather take $\Bbb Q^n$ or $\Bbb Z^n$ which *does* obey the property mentioned.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma. $\Bbb Q^n$ or $\Bbb Z^n$ are countable, of course. But what about $S=\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @zkutch That does not have the property that $B(x) \cap S$ is countable for any radius.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma. In question is words "there is an $n$-ball", which I understand as existence, not universal quantifier. This is why I set question. With $\forall$, of course, is different situation.

Comment: @zkutch it’s an existential quantifier.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma. If you say it is "existential quantifier", then it contradicts with your words  "for any radius" in previous comment.

Comment: @zkutch true, but for no radius is $B(x) \cap S$ countable for $S=\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma. That's why I asked OP about this example. I think $S$ should have some additional restriction.

Comment: @zkutch If $S = \mathbb{R}^n$, then for every$\mathbf{x} \in S$ , then $B(\mathbb{x})\cap S$ is uncountable for any $n$-ball of radius $r >0$., and therefore fails to fulfill the premise of the problem.. That's why we suggest you should not consider $S = \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @user669545. Then this comes in contradiction with "Given a set $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$". As I wrote above you should have some additional restriction.

Answer (score 1):

No, that proof doesn't really work: you claim the existence of largest radii with some property etc. which in general need not exist. It's way easier to use that $S$ has a countable base (being a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$) and so is Lindelöf: the cover $B(x,r_x)$, $x \in S$ where each $r_x$ is chosen so that $B(x,r_x) \cap S$ is countable at most, has a countable subcover and from that it clearly follows that $S$ is countable too.

This argument works in any separable metric space. Don't make it all about $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: I see how you did it. That is much more easier way. But my claim  is  not the exsitence of the largest radii with some property etc. In fact I claim the opposite: All radii, regardless of their length, fulfill the "$B(x;r) \cap S$ is countable" requirement. Sorry, but I felt like we are not on the same page.

Comment: @user669545 If that fails there still need not be a maximal radius such that $B(x_0, r) \cap S$ is countable.

Comment: that's exactly what I have proved, right?

Comment: It's true that I assume there is "the largest radius" with certain properties, but that's just for the sake of contradiction.

Comment: @user669545: Showing that there is no largest radius with the desired property does not show that every radius has the property. It is in principle entirely possible, for instance, that the radii that have the property in question are precisely those that are less than $1$, and this set of radii has no largest element.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott  Yes, Yes... I see what you mean.. and I had this another wrong assumption in mind which is (possibly) against the premise of the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @user669545: You’re welcome!